# Unity plugin using OpenGL for Project Tango

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, google-project-tango, opengl-es-3.0

I am developing an AR app using Unity for Project Tango.

One of the things I am trying to accomplish is getting the frame image from the device while using the AR example they provided with the SDK - 
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity

The problem is that they are using the IExperimentalTangoVideoOverlay which doesn't return the frame buffer (The image is converted from YUV to RGB in the shader).

I've registered to OnExperimentalTangoImageAvailable event and called an android native plugin to use glReadPixles in order to get the frame image, but it didn't work also (maybe since it's a library with no context?)

I am open to other solutions... but this is the code for reading the image frame from the android plugin i am using -

public void Decode() {

```
    try {

        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize);

        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        GLES30.glReadBuffer(GLES30.GL_BACK);
        GLES30.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1920, 1200, GLES30.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

        byte[] myTest = bb.array();

        // for test
        for (int i=0; i<screenshotSize; ++i)
        {
            // Check to see if at least one of the bytes is not zero
            if (myTest[i] != 0)
            {
                Log.d("MYAPP", "I AM NOT ZERO!!");
                break;
            }
        }

        Decode(myTest, 1920, 1200);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MYAPP", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please guys appreciate all the help I can get.
Thanks!

Edited:

Problem solved!
Thanks to Jason Guo.

I should have used GLES20 and NOT GLES30.
Also Android doesn't support GL_LUMINANCE.

The fixed line is -
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

Comment: HI Tako, the shader code shouldn't be a problem. Framebuffer is generated after the fragments shader pass. However, in the sample code, we forced the code to run on GLES20, could you try change the native call to GLES20 to see if it works?

Comment: Thanks Jason!
That was the problem.. I can now take a snapshot of the screen using my plugin :)